# Using Javascript Array in liquid

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopify, jekyll, liquid

Hello everyone I want to use a list I obtained with javascript in liquid and I want to use it in liquid and the codes I wrote are below.

```
<script>

 var queryString = previousURL;

 var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

 var selectedFilmTypes2 = urlParams.getAll('filter.p.m.custom.film_type');

 console.log("value", selectedFilmTypes2)

 window.myLiquidArray = JSON.stringify(selectedFilmTypes2);

 console.log("window", window.myLiquidArray)

</script>


{% assign myLiquidArrayLiquid = myLiquidArray | json %}

 {{ myLiquidArrayLiquid }}

 {% for item in myLiquidArrayLiquid %}

 {{ item }}

 {% endfor %}
```

There is no problem when I check the data with `console.log()`. For example for `console.log("value", selectedFilmTypes2)` the output is `value (2) \['Color Reversal', 'Battery'\]"` and for `console.log("window", window.myLiquidArray)` the output is `window \["Color Reversal", "Battery"\]`. But `{{ myLiquidArrayLiquid }}` and `{{ item }}` return null.

Comment: This will not work, since liquid is run on the server, and the javascript is running on the client. When the javascript starts executing, the liquid code has already run.

Comment: You should look into obtaining the liquid array through the liquid code, instead of javascript. Maybe the "request.params" could be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/configure/liquid/liquid-objects#request

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As an example in the link "https://sitename/collections/film-page?sort_by=manual&filter.p.m.custom.film_type=Battery", according to the microsoft source you gave;
 {% assign id = request.params['id'] | escape %} instead of 
When I do {% assign id = request.params['filter.p.m.custom.movie_type'] | escape %} and print {{id}} in liquid, nothing is returned. Do you think I'm doing something wrong? @BjørnNyborg

Comment: Is your parameter called "filter.p.m.custom.movie_type"? Does it work if you just try to get a parameter called "id"?